# No such element or plugin 'textoverlay'

Tags: gstreamer-1.0

I have build the gst-build in my ubuntu to work with the Gstreamer 1.18.1 version.

```
meson build
ninja -C build
ninja -C build devenv
```

The problem is that I can't get the textoverlay plugin and I don't know why.

```
gst-inspect-1.0 textoverlay
No such element or plugin 'textoverlay'
```

So, how could I get that plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the Textoverlay plugin is shipped with gst-plugins-base. You can  install the missing plugin by:

```
/usr/libexec/gst-install-plugins-helper textoverlay
```

or

```
/usr/lib/gst-install-plugins-helper textoverlay
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: This is not really an answer, the OP mentions "I have build the gst-build in my ubuntu", so it means there is a problematic dependency, installing a system library as the answer suggests will probably install a different version of the plugin.